# Connection Pool has reached the maximum number of connections

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7.5, connection-pooling, informix

This method cause the error file to full with this error :

```
Connection Pool has reached the maximum number of connections
```

---

```
public static int IsValidPortalUser(string p_u, string p_p) {
            int item = 0;
            using (IfxConnection ifxConnection = new IfxConnection(DB_Connection.connectionString))
            {
                IfxCommand ifxCommand = new IfxCommand();
                string str = DB_Connection.My_Decryption_2(p_p);
                try
                {
                    if (ifxConnection.State == 0)
                    {
                        ifxConnection.Open();
                    }
                     DB_Connection.DBCmd = new IfxCommand();
                     DB_Connection.DBCmd.Connection = ifxConnection;
                     DB_Connection.DBCmd.CommandText = "SELECT nvl(emp_num,0) FROM htoemp WHERE username = ? AND DECRYPT_CHAR(password, '78dfdf') = ? ";
                     DB_Connection.DBCmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", p_u);
                     DB_Connection.DBCmd.Parameters.Add("password", str);

                    IfxDataReader ifxDataReaders = ifxCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    using (ifxDataReaders)
                    {
                        if (ifxDataReaders.Read())
                        {
                            item = (int)ifxDataReaders[0];
                        }
                        ifxDataReaders.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (ApplicationException applicationException)
                {
                }
                ifxConnection.Close();
            }
            return item;
        }
```

---

```
   Error Message:Connection Pool has reached the maximum number of connections.  Stack Trace :    at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnectionPool.ReportOpenTimeOut()
   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnectionPool.Open(IfxConnection connection)
   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnPoolManager.Open(IfxConnection connection)
   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.Open()
   at DB_Connection_s.DB_Connection.IsValidPortalUser(String p_u, String p_p)
   at LoginSystem.LoginPage_ar.ValidateUser(String UserName, String Password) in H:\LoginSystem\LoginSystem\LoginPage_ar.aspx.cs:line 20
   at LoginSystem.LoginPage_ar.ibtn_login_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in H:\LoginSystem\LoginSystem\LoginPage_ar.aspx.cs:line 33
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Now i set the `Max Pool Size=400` instead of `Max Pool Size=200`

and until now no errors of this type .but i wanna to know why this method cause this problem .

Comment: What is DB_Connection? Supposing that something goes wrong there because the ifxConnection is created, opened and destroyed, but never used.

Comment: The `ifxConnection` should indeed be closed by the `using`; can I ask, though; what is `DB_Connection.conn` ? just in case it is related... also: as a general thing: why catch/swallow `ApplicationException` ?

Comment: Also you create an ifxCommand, but the sql string is passed to another command. Then the code execute the ifxCommand. I doubt that anything returns in the dataadapter here.

Comment: @Steve:`DB_Connection` is a static class.

@MarcGravell:`DB_Connection.conn` i edit my question sorry .

Comment: So you pass the ifxConnection opened here to your conn property inside the static class. Do you delete that reference  inside the static class? (set conn = null)

Comment: No,i didn't ,but the `ifxConnection` not static

Comment: `using (IfxConnection ifxConnection = new IfxConnection(DB_Connection.connectionString))`

Comment: are you calling this static function somewhere in loop for making connection. if so then please paste that code too maybe you have problem at place where you are calling this function.

Comment: No loops just normal calling.

Answer (score 1):

This is a real shot in the dark, so, let me know if something changes

```
public static int IsValidPortalUser(string p_u, string p_p) 
{ 
    int item = 0; 
    using (IfxConnection ifxConnection = new IfxConnection(DB_Connection.connectionString)) 
    { 
        IfxCommand ifxCommand = new IfxCommand(); 
        string str = DB_Connection.My_Decryption_2(p_p); 
        try 
        { 
            if (ifxConnection.State == 0) 
                ifxConnection.Open(); 
            ifxCommand.Connection = idxConnection; 
            ifxCommand.CommandText = "SELECT nvl(emp_num,0) FROM htoemp WHERE username = ? 
                                      AND DECRYPT_CHAR(password, '78dfdf') = ? "; 
            ifxCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_name", p_u); 
            ifxCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", str); 
            IfxDataReader ifxDataReaders = ifxCommand.ExecuteReader(); 
            using (ifxDataReaders) 
            { 
                if (ifxDataReaders.Read()) 
                { 
                    item = (int)ifxDataReaders[0]; 
                } 
                ifxDataReaders.Close(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return item; 
}
```

Also, depending on your version of Informix, the string password is a [reserved keyword](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1204.htm)